# apache/debian squeeze server loading directory listing instead of website

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, wordpress

when you navigate to mywebsite.com/ you see an apache page showing a folder called mywebsite.com/, clicking there then takes me to mywebsite.com/mywebiste.com which doesn't exist, so wordpress shows me the a 404 error. I'm trying to host a wordpress site at mywebsite.com/ but I think I have some kind of directory listing wrong somewhere, though I'm pretty sure I've set up my /etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.com correctly:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mywebsite.com
ServerAdmin me@mywebsite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com/
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by replacing the

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

with

```
<VirtualHost my.static.ip:80>
```

Comment: The `<VirtualHost>` directive must match the `NameVirtualHost` directive exactly in order for it to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that looks off to me is this line:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com/
```

Change it to, drop the trailing slash, and restart:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com
```

**Edit**:

Next update

```
<Directory />
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/mywebsite.com>
```

Comment: I did that, still doesn't work

Comment: see the updated answer ... try that ...?

Comment: I did.... nothing :L

Comment: When you go this directory `/var/www/mywebsite.com/` on the file system, what do you see?

Comment: I solved it by replacing the virtualhost line with my static ip. Weird. Thanks for the help!